# SetWindowsHookEx fails with error 1428

Tags: c#, windows, setwindowshookex

I try to hook into the start button by the following code.

```
// Create an instance of HookProc.
StartHookProcedure = new CallBack(StartHookProc);
IntPtr desktop = FindWindowEx(
  IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, "Progman", null);                
uint procId = 0;
uint threadId = GetWindowThreadProcessId(desktop, out procId);
Process process = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
ProcessModule module = process.MainModule;

IntPtr hModule = GetModuleHandle(null); // get my module handle...
//IntPtr start = FindWindowEx(desktop, IntPtr.Zero, "Button", null);

hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_GETMESSAGE,
  StartHookProcedure, hModule, (int)threadId);
//If the SetWindowsHookEx function fails.
if (hHook == 0)
{
  int err = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
  MessageBox.Show("SetWindowsHookEx Failed" + err.ToString());
  return;
}
```

SetWindowHookEx always runs into error 1428 ERROR_HOOK_NEEDS_HMOD

> Cannot set nonlocal hook without a module handle.

I can't understand this. It fails although I'm calling `GetModuleHandle(null)`.

Comment: You can't make this work as intended.  The module handle must be a handle to a DLL, you are passing the handle of your EXE.  Furthermore, the DLL gets injected into other processes.  Which means it cannot be a DLL written in C#, those other processes don't have the CLR loaded.  You must write one in a native language, like C.  Some guidance here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18638/Using-Window-Messages-to-Implement-Global-System-H

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. Is it possible to make the callbacks visible to a clr application? Like loading the unmanaged dll, injecting and pointing to a callback defined in the clr-app?

Comment: No callback, you are crossing a process boundary.  A named pipe is common.  Read the article I linked.